# Saving user list data in android compose

Tags: android, kotlin, save, autosave

So im trying to understand how data is saved on android. I am currently working on a simple notes app. How it currently works, is the user creates a new note, types whatever they want, and once they hit the back button that entry is saved in to a list. I am using compose viewmodel so the entries are saved up until the point the app is destroyed. what is the best way to save the list entries so they are pemenantly saved on the phone. This is also just a general question on how apps generally save user input data that is not saved in the cloud.

here is some example of the code.

```
data class NotesBlueprint(
    val header: String,
    val note: String,
    val key: Int
)


data class NotesVars(
    val header:String = "", <<<< instance of header and the note
    val note: String = ""   <<<<
    var list: List<NotesBlueprint> = mutableListOf() <<< list that the Notes are saved in to 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data on android via Shared Preference, Database, and Files. This [storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) guide gives the idea regarding different types of the storage system and how they are saved on android.

In your case, if you want to save notes which user has written, it would be better to go with the database.

Android provides the Room library for storing data in the local database. You can check out the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Comment: I agree.. in my notes app I used room database. Then I can allow it to be saved to the phone as a backup. Then pull that DB into my premium side and port users over from the free side to premium side with firebase. However, cloud computing is the way to go. If the files are saved in the cloud then you don't have to worry about the files if you change phones. So with mine Notes app on Play Store that's what I do. Free is room DB and paid version is cloud storage.